# Vue Web Component : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, web-component, micro-frontend

I am facing issue while consuming Vue web component in a shell application and this shell application is also developed in Vue.

My Vue web component has its own Vue router and inside router.js of this web component I wrote `Vue.use(VueRouter)`. Similarly my shell application has its own Vue router where I also used same `Vue.use(VueRouter)` inside their router.js.

I added my web components js (webcomponet-project/dist/sample-web-component.js) in shell application's `index.html` file like below:

```
<script src = "../webcomponet-project/dist/sample-web-component.js"></script>
```

Now when i am starting shell application I am getting the following error?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot redefine property: $router
```

What can I do to get rid of this error?

Comment: Did you ever work this out? I'm having the exact same issue atm.